# How to track down what is stopping an application from closing

Tags: memory-leaks, ants

My .net application process will not stop running.  I can use ANTS to profile it, but all examples talk about increasing memory and new instances.  How do I find out what is preventing the application from exiting.

I have done snapshots while the application is running properly and then a second snapshot after it is "closed" but is still running as a process.  What should I be looking for?